# Image Set in a custom Listview is being Unset when the Listview is scrolled

Tags: android, android-listview

The Listview has a default image which I am replacing it with the another image when, the Image is selected (Shown below - onClickListener). The Problem is the image that replaces the deault image is reverted back to the default image when the listView goes out and Comes back into the View.

```
public class BookViewCustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> chapter;
private final ArrayList<String> verse;
private final ArrayList<String> content;
private final Integer[] imageId;

public BookViewCustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<String> chapter, ArrayList<String> verse, Integer[] imageId, ArrayList<String> content) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_book_view_layout, chapter);
    this.context = context;
    this.chapter = chapter;
    this.verse = verse;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.content = content;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_book_view_layout, null, true);

    TextView txtChapter = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChapter);
    txtChapter.setText(chapter.get(position));

    TextView txtVerse = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVerse);
    txtVerse.setText(verse.get(position));

    //ImageView imageViewBookmark = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBookmark);
    //imageViewBookmark.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    TextView txtContent = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewContent);
    txtContent.setText(content.get(position));


    final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBookmark);
    imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_blue);
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

}

So how to retain the changes that have been made? Thanks!

Comment: Use view holder pattern http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your own data model with a checked or selected item and then you need to maintain the model.For Example write a model for your adapter as-

```
public class Book{
 private String chapter;
 private String verse;
 private String content;
 private int imageID;
 private boolean isChecked;
}
```

Set-up the getter and setter methods also for the same and modify the adapter for the above type as `ArrayAdapter<Book>`.
Now you can modify your `getView()` method for the `onClick()` to make your model item checked or unchecked and setting the image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

seems that you haven't use viewHolder pattern.

try this

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(view==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_book_view_layout, viewGroup, false);

    holder.txtChapter = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChapter);
    holder.txtVerse = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVerse);
    holder.txtContent = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewContent);
    //ImageView imageViewBookmark = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBookmark);
    holder.imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBookmark);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtChapter.setText(chapter.get(position));
    holder.txtVerse.setText(verse.get(position));
    //imageViewBookmark.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    holder.txtContent.setText(content.get(position));

    holder.imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_blue);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtChapter, txtVerse, txtContent;
    ImageView imgView;
}
```

Comment: okay I gotch ya 
remove LaoutInflater from getview Method and try initialize inflater in you adapter constructor as

inflater = LayoutIflater.from(context);